# Issue in populating label for a dependent drop down

Tags: javascript

Labels of a dropdown2 is not visible, while its values gets populated when checked via inspect element in browser.

```js
         function populate(s1,s2)
         {
          var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
          var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);  
    
          s2.innerHTML = "";
          if (s1.value == "Chevy") {
           var optionArray = ["|","chevy1|Chevy1","chevy2|Chevy2","chevy3|Chevy3"];
          } else if (s1.value == "Dodge") {
           var optionArray = ["|","dodge1|Dodge1","dodge2|Dodge2","dodge3|Dodge3"];
          } else if (s1.value == "Ford") {
           var optionArray = ["|","ford1|Ford1","ford2|Ford2","ford3|Ford3"];
          } 
          for (var option in optionArray) {
           var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
           var newOption = document.createElement("option");
           newOption.value = pair[0];
           //alert(newOption.value);   
           newOption.InnerHTML = pair[1];
           s2.options.add(newOption); 
          }
        }
```

```html
    <h2>Choose Your Car</h2>
    <hr/>
    <h2> Choose make car </h2>
    <select id="slct1" name="slct1" onchange="populate(this.id,'slct2')">
     <option value=""></option>
     <option value="Chevy">Chevy</option>
     <option value="Dodge">Dodge</option>       
        <option value="Ford">Ford</option> 
    </select>
    <hr/>
    <h2> Choose car model</h2>
    <select id="slct2" name="slct2"></select>
    <hr/>
```

Desired output:

Since dropdown2 with id="slct2" is dependent on selection of dropdown1, the desired output should be like if I select label 'Chevy' of dropdown1 than dorpdown2 should be populated with values'chevy1','chevy2','chevy3' and respected labels as 'Chevy1','Chevy2','Chevy3'.

Though while checking via inspect element the values are getting populated but Labels are not visible that is why when I clickon dropdown2 blank list is coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is  (dont forget to add 'DOMContentLoaded...' to your code ( the snippet here bypass it)

```js
  const
    selCarBrand  = document.getElementById('Car-Brand'),
    selCarModel  = document.getElementById('Car-Model'),
    CarsModels   = {
      'Chevy': [ ['chevy1','Chevy1'], ['chevy2','Chevy2'], ['chevy3','Chevy3']],
      'Dodge': [ ['dodge1','Dodge1'], ['dodge2','Dodge2'], ['dodge3','Dodge3']],
      'Ford' : [ ['ford1','Ford1'],   ['ford2','Ford2'],   ['ford3','Ford3']]
    }
  ;
  
  selCarBrand.onchange = function()
  {
    selCarModel.innerHTML = null;
    if ('' != selCarBrand.value)
    {
      CarsModels[selCarBrand.value].forEach( function(pair,item)
      {
        selCarModel[item]= new Option(pair[0],pair[1]);
      })
    }
  }
```

```html
<h2>Choose Your Car</h2>
<hr />
<h2> Choose make car</h2>
<select id="Car-Brand" >
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Chevy">Chevy</option>
  <option value="Dodge">Dodge</option>
  <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
</select>
<hr />
<h2> Choose car model</h2>
<select id="Car-Model" >
</select>
<hr />
```

Answer (score 0):

this a basic one, browsers interpret all code; if you place JS code before HTML code, when he work on the JS part (in your case) Body parts does not exist at this time, like dropdown2 etc..

please read => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {

    // place you code here...
  });
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Dear MrJ I have placed the javascript code as per suggested but still no luck instead this time neither the value got populated nor labels.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
 ///my js code
});
</script>

Comment: course, because your code are still plenty of nonsens, let me  more time to see that